# Refactor non-standard library callback into promise

Tags: javascript, promise, asynccallback

I am using the fabricjs package and want to make use of the `fabric.Image.fromURL` function. The documentation for this function is below:

> (static) `fromURL(url, callbackopt, imgOptionsopt)`
>
> Creates an instance of `fabric.Image` from an URL string
> Parameters:
>
> | Name | Type | Attributes | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | url | String |  | URL to create an image from |
> | callback | function | <optional> | Callback to invoke when image is created (newly created image is passed as a first argument). Second argument is a boolean indicating if an error occurred or not. |
> | imgOptions | Object | <optional> | Options object |

I would to refactor my code to use modern Promise notation instead of nesting callbacks. Can I refactor this function into a Promise?

Currently if I want to add two images in a row, my code looks like this:

```
  # add first image
  fabric.Image.fromURL(url1, function (oImg: any) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
    # add second image
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url2, function (oImg: any) {
      canvas.add(oImg);
    }  
  })
```

I would love to be able to rewrite it as

```
async def addImages() {
    await promisifiedImageFromURL(url1)
    await promisifiedImageFromURL(url2)
}
```

I have looked into `util.promisify` (https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) but this function expects the corresponding function to be in a specific format: a single error-first callback.  The `fromURL` function, on the other hand, is in a nonstandard format, which is where I am having trouble

I'm looking into custom promisified functions, but I'm honestly in over my head here

Comment: `util.promisify` does not expect two callbacks, it expects a single error-first callback. The example with separate onError and onSuccess callbacks is showing a [custom promisified function](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#custom-promisified-functions), creating a `new Promise` and interfacing appropriately with the non-standard function, which is what you should be doing here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const promiseFromUrl = (url, imgOptions) => {

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {

    const callback = (image, isError) => {
      if (isError) rej(new Error('Some error occurred'));
      else res(image);
    };
    fromURL(url, callback, imageOptions);

  });

}
```